# How to prevent WebService fault from beeing logged in the sys.out?

Tags: java, log4j, jax-ws

I am using JAX-WS webservice and I throw an Exception back to the client. I also use Log4J as my logging framework and Glassfish as my appServer.

The exception I throw extends the normal Exception class and annotated as @WebFault.
The client gets the correct Error message, and displays a nice message to the user.

So far so good.

The problem is: The exception is also logged in the sys.out, with all the stacktrace - and I don't want that!! I do print something to the log using Log4J - but I don't need anything else massing up my sys.out.

Can you help me please?

Thank you, 
IDO

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible problems:

a) sys.out is used somewhere in application code  to print stacktrace, in which case find it and fix it.

b) Some of the libraries you are using are getting that Exception and logging it to sys.out in which case you should prevent Exception from reaching such library.